# Quickest way to get the character · typed in?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently, when I need to type · into Word or other programs (Windows 7), I am using the keyboard combination: Hold ALT and type: 0183, result is ·

Sometimes there are 100s of occurences in mathematics text, this is why I try to find a shorter way to get this character in the text.

Copy and paste takes also too long.

Maybe someone has an idea how this situation could be improved?

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure that you can improve it by using a macro that you can program for a hotkey to paste the desired text. Here's one that I use. www.autohotkey.com 
You could also program it for if you type "multiply" it would use the dot.